# Android app doesn't connect to a Bluetooth Low Energy device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, psoc

I'm starting with Android development, and I'm trying to make a simple bluetooth low energy connection between my android phone and a microcontroller (PSoC4BLE) to write a value in one of the microcontroller characteristics.

As I already know the microcontroller MAC, and the service and characteristic UUID, i just want that as soon as my android app opens, it makes the connection to the microcontroller without any user interaction, and that when i press a button, the app writes a value into a characteristic.

The problem is that my app crash when i run it, and in the cases when tweaking the code i get it work, it doesn't connect to the microcontroller, what i'm doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// bluetooth variables
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mMyCharacteristic;
private static final UUID CAR_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-1000-1000-100000000000");
private static final UUID CAR_CHARACTERISTIC = UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-2000-2000-200000000000");
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // initialize bluetooth adapter
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    // create a device that represents the bluetooth device and assign it's known MAC address
    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:A0:50:0F:13:1C");

    // make the connection to the device
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(MainActivity.this, false, mGattCallback);

    // get a reference to my user interface button
    Button btnWrite = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnWrite);

    // define the button behaviour
    btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // create the characteristic variable
            byte[] value = new byte[1];
            value[0] = (byte) 1;
            mMyCharacteristic.setValue(value);
            // set the service UUID and the characteristic UUID
            mMyCharacteristic = mBluetoothGatt.getService(CAR_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(CAR_CHARACTERISTIC);
            // write the characteristic en the device
            mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mMyCharacteristic);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**UPDATE 1**
Finally i get a logcat, and it says:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lenovo.car/lenovo.car.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Please, some idea? I found that the app crash at
`final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:A0:50:0F:13:1C");`

Comment: could you please post the logcat from the crash?

Comment: i'm sorry, but i've got a bq phone, and i updated it to android lollipop 5.0 last week, and since that the drivers of ADB doesn't work, so i can't access logcat. Also my device isn't rooted, so i can't install any log app.  Besides the logcat, please do you see at a glance some java or android api mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

You do not connect to the remote device actually.

```
// make the connection to the device
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(MainActivity.this, false, mGattCallback);
```

Obtaining BluetoothGatt instance is not enought, you need to invoke `mBluetoohGatt.connect()` method on the Gatt object.

Notice also that `mBluetoohGatt.connect()` returns boolean indicating whether connection request was sent.

Furthermore, in next step connection state should be changed. This is notified via

[mGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)) method.

Once the connection is established you should send request in order to obtain device services. This is available via

[mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#discoverServices()) method.

If services discovery request succeeds you should receive all services of your device.

You can then obtain all services and characteristics of your device. You can assume at this point that you are connected to the remote device on condition that the device does not require any authentication.

In order to read current value under specific characteristic you must

call [mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#readCharacteristic(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic)) applying the characteristic the value of which you want to find out.

The characteristic with value inserted should be notified via [mGattCallback.onCharacteristicRead()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int)). This works under the condition that the characteristic with the value you are requesting for is readable.

In order to write current value under specific characteristic you must

call mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic() applying the characteristic with new value.

As a confirmation of your request you should get notification via [mBluetoothGatt.onCharacteristicWrite()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onCharacteristicWrite(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int)). This works if your characteristic is writable.

Hope that helps somehow.

Comment: thank you, but the exact code post above, and your mBluetoothGatt.connect() addition still ends in a crash, so i could not test it.

Comment: Your crash log indicates that the initial problem is far earlier than any parts of the code mentioned in this answer: you don't have a valid adapter instance.